Angular 18 Material 3 Font Size
I've been trying to upgrade from Material 2 to  Material 3, and so far I have
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@use 'm3-theme';

@include mat.core();
@include mat.all-component-typographies();

html {
  @include mat.all-component-themes(m3-theme.$light-theme);
}

In my Material 2 configuration I have
$typography-config: mat.m2-define-typography-config(
        $font-family:   'Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif',
        $body-2:        mat.m2-define-typography-level(14px, 24px, 500),
        $body-1:        mat.m2-define-typography-level(14px, 20px, 400),
        $button:        mat.m2-define-typography-level(14px, 36px, 500, $letter-spacing: 0.014rem),
);

But I can't seem to find how to specify the font size in Material 3.
I've been reading https://material.angular.io/guide/theming and https://material.angular.io/guide/typography but I can't seem to find relevant information, or perhaps I am missing something.
Could someone point me in the right direction to the right way to change Material 3 font sizes etc.
Thank you.

From what I can see in the source code (Github reference) I do not find any way to customize the size of the font for m3.
Until there is a granular function that helps to set the font size at the library level, it is difficult to customize consistently!
I guess they are trying to keep it consistent for M3 themes Material 3 typography
You will be able to customize

Customizing your colors
Customizing your typography
Customizing your density

For the theme level, the typography can be customized like so
$theme: mat.define-theme((
      typography: (
        brand-family: Comic Sans,
        plain-family: Wingdings,
        bold-weight: 300,
        medium-weight: 200,
        regular-weight: 100,
      )
));

If you want to keep the customizations of the M2 theme, then you can try the below code, it seems to apply the M2 customizations on top of the M3 theme!
@include mat.core();
@include mat.color-variants-backwards-compatibility($theme);
$typography-config: mat.m2-define-typography-config(
  $font-family: 'Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif',
  $body-2: mat.m2-define-typography-level(14px, 24px, 500),
  $body-1: mat.m2-define-typography-level(14px, 20px, 400),
  $button:
    mat.m2-define-typography-level(14px, 36px, 500, $letter-spacing: 0.014rem),
);

@include mat.typography-hierarchy($typography-config);

Stackblitz Demo

Have you maybe found any way to customize levels?
